# Android show AlertDialog on popup Activity

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I am trying to add an `AlertDialog` to popup from a popup Activity (which is an Activity that extends Activity with `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` in the Manifest. I am using:

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
// Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setTitle("Add Extra");
final EditText base = new EditText(builder.getContext());
final EditText value = new EditText(builder.getContext());
base.setHint("Name");
value.setHint("Value");
// Specify the type of input expected; this, for example, sets the input as a password, and will mask the text
base.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
value.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
layout.addView(base);
layout.addView(value);
builder.setView(layout);
builder.setMessage("")
.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

       }
       })
       .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
          // User cancelled the dialog
       }
       });
 // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

to create my Alert, but I recieve an error about not having the correct context. Is there a specific way to get the context of the popup dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Android AlertDialog in Activity Dialog.Theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45910212/android-alertdialog-in-activity-dialog-theme)

I asked this question again and it was answered for anyone else having this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are using getApplicationContext(), use Activity context instead

Use this instead to avoid errors

```
Context context = YourCurrentActivity.this;
```

Comment: I receive this error: `You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.`

Comment: Is your activity extending from ActionBarActivity or AppCompatActivity? if so, extend from Activity or any other answer in this question might come on handy https://stackoverflow.com/a/21815015/7355128

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look. I am extending Activity instead of AppCompatActivity because I have the theme Dialog.

Comment: This doesn't answer why the AlertDialog isn't working on this do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Activity context.

Change this line,

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
```

to this:

```
Context context = this;
```